# Displaying value in the Frontend (React component) which is a foreign key in django models

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am learning django rest framework. I want to get author full name in JSON and not id, Below is `GET request`, is there a way if any? Created the `Articles` from admin site. I am trying to get the value in the Frontend with `article.author`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "article_title": "Premier League",
        "description": "The Premier League is the top level of the English football league system. Contested by 20 clubs, it operates on a system of promotion and relegation with the English Football League. The Premier League is a corporation in which the member clubs act as shareholders.",
        "created_at": "2019-10-02T08:59:24.883450Z",
        "author": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "article_title": "Cricket in England",
        "description": "Cricket is one of the most popular sports in England, and has been played since the 16th century. Marylebone Cricket Club, based at Lord's, developed the modern rules of play and conduct.",
        "created_at": "2019-10-02T08:59:57.075912Z",
        "author": 2
    },

]
```

Render function of a react component. `article.author_id` gives blank and `article.author_id` displays the author `id` as an `integer`. What should i return to display author full name?

```
render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h2>Articles</h2>
            <div >
                {
                    this.props.articles.map(article => (
                        <div className="card" key={article.id}>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <div className="card-title"> <b>{article.article_title}</b></div>
                                <div className="card-text"> {article.description}</div>
                                <div> Author: {article.author_id}</div>
                                <div className="card-footer text-muted"> Created date: {article.created_at}</div>
                            </div>
                            <br></br>
                        </div>

                    ))

                }
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

Model class of the app, containing the fields

```
#model class
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Articles(models.Model):
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):enter code here
        return self.article_title
```

Serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Lead, Author, Articles


# Author Serializer
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = '__all__'

#Article serializer
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Articles
    fields = '__all__'
```

API class containing Viewset to view the api calls

```
from .models import Author,Articles
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import  AuthorSerializer, ArticleSerializer

#Author Viewset
class AuthorViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer

#Article Viewset

class ArticlesViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat the full name, annotate it onto the queryset and then add it to the serializer:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

class ArticlesViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = Articles.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.annotate(
            authors_name=Concat('author__first_name', Value(" "), 'author__last_name')
        )

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = ('article_title', 'description', 'created_at', 'authors_name')
```

Comment: added "author = serializers.CharField(required=False)" in ArticleSerializer class and it did the trick. Help appreciated @hancho

Answer (score 0):

I made the following change in the serializers class and I was able to get the author name

```
#Article serializer
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  author = serializers.CharField(required=False)
  class Meta:
    model = Articles
    fields = ('article_title', 'description','created_at', 'author')
```